# Attempting to add duplicate resource : guava-11.0.2.jar

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, tez

I am trying to run a pig script using Tez Mode . 
I am able to execute my pig script in local mode i.e pig -x tez_local
but I am getting an error when I execute same pig script in tez mode i.e pig -x tez

I am attaching a screenshot which describes the error details . [tez mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYNBE.png)

I am using pig 0.14.0 and tez 0.5.4 , Hadoop-2.6.0
Please some one help me out to remove this error .

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TEZ-1697

The current workaround as suggested in the JIRA is - *specifying tgz file in tez.lib.uris instead of directory to avoid this.*

Also, Looks like the issue is fixed in Tex 0.6.0. Please check if you can update your version.

Comment: which "tgz file" ?

Comment: I think what is being suggested is to package all your tez dependencies in a tgz file and point the property `tez.lib.uris` to the tgz file

Comment: I Replaced ted 0.5 with 0.6.2 . I am getting a new error "Tezsession has alredy expired" . [link]http://postimg.org/image/z2owgiict/

Comment: I am facing many compatibility issues caused by apache opensource  softwares  creating headache for me . Which version of pig and tez should I install to overcome this problem . I am using java 1.6 with Hadoop2.6 .

Comment: Even after upgrading tez from 0.5.2 to 0.6.2 and running pig script in tez cluster mode you can observe in screen shot that tez version is still 0.5.2 . I completely removed the tez 0.5.2 folder and replaced it with 0.6.2

Comment: pig and tez versions that you mentioned require java 1.7 or higher. Not sure if thats the reason for the problem though. Can you try updating your java version? https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_installing_manually_book/content/meet-min-system-requirements.html